# Air pump selection

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium

I'd be really thankful if anyone who owns any of the air pumps mentioned in this article https://fishtankclub.com/aquarium-air-pump/ could tell me which one is the best, from either personal experience or an estimation. They all sound promising and I'm clueless and don't know which one to go for. My only requirements are that the air pump has to be on the cheaper side, isn't complicated to install and fairly easy to maintain (although I'm new to the world of aquariums, I don't want to invest in a weak air pump).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) Your question sounds a little bit opinion based. Perhaps you could reword it to ask 'What makes a great air pump?' or similar. That way we don't have to rely on the link you posted with it (in case it goes down).

Comment: what do you need it to do,how deep is your aquarium-is it for a filter-is it just to make bubbles and adding oxygen to your tank.

Comment: The vibrator type air pumps usually have a life of less than two years, so it won't make a big difference. Also there are different models from one manufacturer with different life times.